# Another word for workbench or tools?

Tags: word-choice

I'm about to launch a website that will help business by providing them various tools (management tools mostly) they require to run their business.

I would like a word to capture the objective of the site. Workbench is the best I've come up with so far but I really do not like the way it sounds.

Do you guys have any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: This sounds more like a creative writing exercise related to naming. That's typically off topic here, as stated in the Help Center http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Get your metaphor settled before you look for words to fit it. Otherwise the coherence isn't clear to the audience and you wind up with a mess.

Answer (score 2):

How about *toolkit*? It is [defined as:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/toolkit)

> a set of tools designed to be used together or for a particular purpose

The term is also widely used for things like online modules and resources. Take for example this online [National Preparedness Month 2013 Toolkit](http://community.fema.gov/connect.ti/readynpm/view?objectId=3200688) from FEMA.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more aggressive term, consider **[arsenal](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/arsenal?q=arsenal)**

> an array of resources available for a certain purpose:
>   *we have an arsenal of computers at our disposal*

[But I do like @JLG's *toolkit*]

Comment: And Arsenal are top of the Premier League right now!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how extensive you want to imply your set of tools is.

**Toolkit** is often used in the computer world, but implies a small kit of tools for a given purpose.  **Tool cabinet** is also used, and one can infer a much larger assortment of tools, to accomplish task desired.  **Arsenal**, as above, is aggressive ... perhaps even implying hostile competition, even weaponry.

Answer (score -3):

What about *apparatus*?  I think that can be a good word if you don't want to use *workbench* or *toolkit*.  (I advise to use *toolkit*, though.)

Comment: This site is about English usage. Please can you use English in your answers.